Forced to be in tty1 when switching another tty
I have GUI problem on ubuntu 22.04, when I switch to another tty with CTRL+ALT+F(2/3/4/5/5) so that I can interact with CLI, the OS will redirect me to tty1 (main display) back after 1 second which I can't input user and pass and just displaying stuck.

After failing to switch to (say) VT #2, what does systemctl status getty@tty2.service say?

Nevermind, I login from SSH and then reinstall ubuntu-desktop
